# Ionic 3: Display text in multiple line

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, mobile-development

Thanks for reading my post.

I just started developing an app in Ionic 3 and there is an issue I ran into. I want to have a box to enter text into. When I use following code, I can enter both single line text as well as multiple line text.

`<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Message</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="_message" name="message"></ion-textarea>
</ion-item>`

But the issue is that the size of the box does not change. As I press Enter and type more words, the upper text hides because the view scrolls down. There is still space left in the view and I tried to adjust it, but couldn't.

Also, upon doing Google research, I did found a comment mentioning that this is a defect in Ionic Framework. But, I am not sure.

Thank You

Comment: see here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ion-textarea-resize-height-dynamically/80885/2

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't dynamically grow by itself. But you can increase the number of rows statically by adding `rows`.

```
<ion-textarea rows="5" [(ngModel)]="_message" name="message"></ion-textarea>
```

You can also try to modify its size dynamically yourself. [Here is a sample code](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/dynamically-change-the-number-of-lines-for-text-input-field/16529/5) that does this.